# Set base value for column to descend

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization

Is it possible to make the column go down with positive numbers?

I need to create a bar chart that the base is 100%, those below 100% will go down and those above 100% will go up, all values are positive.

[Exemple chart](https://ap.imagensbrasil.org/image/rhNv3n)

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function init() {
        google.load("visualization", "1.1", {
            packages: ["corechart"],
            callback: 'grafico'
        });
    }

    function grafico() {

        var dados = <?php  echo $dadosGrafico; ?>;

        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(dados);

        var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);

        view.setColumns([0,
            1, {
                type: 'string',
                role: 'annotation',
                sourceColumn: 1,
                calc: 'stringify'
            }
        ]);

        var options = {
            title: 'Percent state',
            vAxis: {
                title: 'Percent %',
            },
            hAxis: {
                title: 'State',
                textStyle: {
                    fontSize: 12,
                },
            },
            chartArea: {
                bottom: 300,
                left: 200,
                top: 90,
                width: 1200,
            },
            legend: 'bottom',
        };

        var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('chart'));

        chart.draw(view, options);
    }
</script>
```

The data coming from the bank will be in this format.

```
$data = [
        [
            'Group', 'Percent'
        ],
        [
            '19', 78.011
        ],
        [
            '20', 120.4
        ],
        [
            '21', 94.996
        ],
        [
            '22', 100
        ],
    ];
```

I am using the older version of google charts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

simple, set the y-axis baseline at 100.

use config option...

```
  vAxis: {
      baseline: 100,
  }
```

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  packages: ['corechart']
}).then(grafico);

function grafico() {
  var dados = [
      [
          'Group', 'Percent'
      ],
      [
          '19', 78.011
      ],
      [
          '20', 120.4
      ],
      [
          '21', 94.996
      ],
      [
          '22', 100
      ],
  ];;

  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(dados);

  var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);

  view.setColumns([0,
      1, {
          type: 'string',
          role: 'annotation',
          sourceColumn: 1,
          calc: 'stringify'
      }, {
          type: 'string',
          role: 'style',
          calc: function (dt, row) {
            var color;
            if (dt.getValue(row, 1) < 100) {
              color = 'red';
            } else {
              color = 'blue';
            }
            return color;
          }
      }
  ]);

  var options = {
      title: 'Percent state',
      vAxis: {
          baseline: 100,
          title: 'Percent %',
      },
      hAxis: {
          title: 'State',
          textStyle: {
              fontSize: 12,
          },
      },
      chartArea: {
          bottom: 300,
          left: 200,
          top: 90,
          width: 1200,
      },
      legend: 'bottom',
  };

  var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('chart'));

  chart.draw(view, options);
}
```

```css
#chart {
  height: 600px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart"></div>
```

---

**NOTE:**

the `jsapi` loader is out of date and should no longer be used.

instead, use `loader.js`, this will only change the `load` statement.
see above snippet...

Comment: Thank you for your help!
I am using laravel snappy to generate pdf, the project is in laravel 5.2, for some reason the laravel snappy version is not generating pdf with latest version of google chart.
Sorry for not knowing how to use the snippet.

Comment: Could I change the color of the column below, for example red below and blue above?

Comment: sure, for color, just add another view column for the style role, changed answer above...

Comment: If you want to post the pdf code in another question, I can try to get it to work with the new version...